# How do I install KDE 4.7 RC on Kubuntu?

Tags: kde, kubuntu

I'm interested in installing KDE 4.7 on my laptop running Kubuntu 11.04, but when I go to the [official page](http://kde.org/announcements/announce-4.7-rc1.php), all the links point me to the [4.6.90 page](http://www.kde.org/info/4.6.90.php).  Does anyone know where I can find the 4.7 RC1 files and instructions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Compiling 4.7 RC1**
>   The complete source code for 4.7 RC1 may be [freely downloaded](http://download.kde.org/stable/4.6.90/src/). Instructions on compiling and installing 4.7 RC1 are available from the [4.7 RC1 Info Page](http://kde.org/info/4.6.90.php).

`KDE SC 4.6.90` is the RC for `KDE 4.7`.

You need to compile the source files by yourself.

The final release is planned for July 27, 2011.